# How to access a hidden input with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

What I am attempting to do is is access hidden object in a div. What happends is a user will click on button that will then perform some task such as delete a user. This may be easier if I show what I have.

```
<div class="mgLine">
    <input type="hidden" name="tenentID" value="1">
    <p class="mgName">James Gear</p>
    <input type="text" class="mgBill" value="" placeholder="Post Bill Link Here">
    <a href="#" class="mgButton" onclick="alertTest(this)">Submit Bill</a>
    <a href="#" class="mgNP">Not Paid</a>
    <a href="#" class="mgButton">Change Password</a>
    <a href="#" class="mgButton">Delete User</a>
</div>
```

What I want the system to do is alert the value of one which it gets from the hidden field when the "submit bill" is pressed.

```
function alertTest(e){
//e.parentNode
window.alert(e.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("tenentID")[0]);
}
```

I am attempting to use JavaScript DOM to access the element. I hope this made at least some sense. There will be many of these entries on the page.

Comment: use getElementsByName instead of getElementsByTagName

Comment: Always the first child? If so, `e.parentNode.children[0]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `getElementsByName` instead of `getElementsByTagName`

```
function alertTest(e){
//e.parentNode
window.alert(document.getElementsByName("tenentID")[0]);
}
```

getElementsByTagName is for selecting elements based on its tag say div, input etc..

#### [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName)

#### [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName)

Realizing that you might have multiple div section and your hidden input is the first child you could use these:-

```
e.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
```

or

```
e.parentNode.firstElementChild.value;
```

if it is not the firstCHild and you know the position then you could use

```
e.parentNode.children(n).value; //n is zero indexed here
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PRqbT/)

Comment: When I was looking into this, I was getting the error: `Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'getElementsByName'` (I was using code identical to yours). However, `document.getElementsByName("tenentID")[0]` worked.

Comment: This looks like it will work for what I am trying to do. Thank you so much for your help and everyone else's!

Answer (score 6):

The modern method would be to use `querySelector`.

```
e.parentNode.querySelector("[name=tenentID]");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/zU2Gh/

However you could also do it with some more manual DOM parsing:

```
var nodes = e.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input"), x;
for (x = 0; x < nodes.length; x++) {
    if (nodes[x].name === "tenentID") {
        console.log(nodes[x]);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/zU2Gh/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function alertTest(e){
    alert(e.parentNode.getElementsByName("tenentID")[0].value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually set an id attribute on the hidden element, then use `getElementById`.

```
<input type="hidden" id="tenentID" name="tenentID" value="1">
```

then I can use...

```
var tenentValue = document.getElementById("tenentID").value;
```

Comment: What if there are several of them? Seems that's likely the case here.

Answer (score 0):

In general, your best bet for accessing a specific element is to give it an ID and then use getElementById().

```
function alertTest(ID){
  alert(document.getElementById(ID).value);
}
```

Names can be duplicated on a page, but the ids have to be unique.